# Ubuntu for Acer Aspire One ZG5 netbook

Tags: system-installation, acer, ubuntu-netbook

I am using a Acer Aspire One ZG5 netbook (1 gb ram) and it is currently running Microsoft Windows XP. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but it is not working properly and it takes a long time to open apps and browser. Please suggest me which version of Ubuntu will be best suitable for this  netbook.

Comment: Xubuntu or Lubuntu should be fine.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 18.04 is the last LTS with 32b support - I just installed it on a ZG5 upgraded with SSD and 1.5GB of RAM and it works seamlessly. Xubuntu 20.04 (Focal) also still has 32b builds.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, I'm sorry to say, but I think you already have the right OS installed. I have the same Acer Aspire One ZG5, upgraded to 1.5gb RAM. When support for WinXP was stopped, I removed it from mine and installed Ubuntu 14.04 32bit. It does take time to open applications, and it lags when streaming video(especially on sites that have advertisements). This Acer Aspire is a limited and slow computer when compared to newer technologies. But there is something about this laptop that I love. I can't explain it. I am using it right now to write this. I still use it for watching videos, Netflix, Youtube(with some lag), and everything else even though I have other options. I also bought an extended battery for mine as well. I hope you enjoy yours as much as I enjoy mine. If I find out any ways to speed it up I'll spread the word.

Answer (score 0):

Max out the ram at 2gb and get a SSD for the hard drive and it super speeds these little netbooks. I use my netbook for work. it is an HP 110 running 10.04. I mostly use it for troubleshooting network issues and email at work. I would like to upgrade to 14.04, but I have become too attached to the netbook GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on the ZG5 and it works. It works best with the Lubuntu desktop or, at least, using 2D Unity. I will use 12.04 as long as it supported. But I can imagine that 14.04 Lubuntu will still work  (--if I am not mistaken then 14.04 does not offer the 2D version).